# Empty comments field or <15 characters

Tags: comments

I would like to hide/lock the submit button to prevent comments with 15 characters or less 
 
for subscriber and contributers in the comment section below postings/pages.
It should automaticly be visible/unlocked as soon there is an input of >15 characters.
(Prevents also *(if possible at all)* sending users to the error page if there is no input at all)

Having a max of 500 characters and then a lock on the submit btn when there are to many characters would also be nice.
*(Research show options for minimum characters but result  in sending to the so named

error page of Wordpress. Possible that my research wasn't correct, if so, sorry.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use jQuery on the client side to handle this validation. There are a number of ways you can achieve this, though one of the easiest would be to use a ready made solution of which one can be found [HERE](http://learneveryday.net/jquery/plugins/twitter-like-textboxs-text-restriction-and-disable-submit-button-with-jquery/)

You'll need to download the plugin file and include it within your header.php file like so;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/charCount.js"/></script>
```

Directly beneath the above line you will then place the following;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         //custom usage
         $("#txtTweet").charCount({
             allowed: 500,
             minChar: 15,
             warning: 20,
             counterText: 'Characters left: ',
             disableControl: '#btnSubmit',
             isDisable: true // is the control disable or not
         });
 });
 </script>
```

Make sure that the above snippets of code are placed within your;

```
<head>

    // usual head stuff here

    <?php wp_head();?>

    // include the charCount.js

    // include the custom usage snippet

</head>
```

The reason you include your files after `wp_head` is that this function will usually output your `jQuery.js` file which needs to be declared before your `charCount.js` and custom code to work correctly.

That link again is [HERE](http://learneveryday.net/jquery/plugins/twitter-like-textboxs-text-restriction-and-disable-submit-button-with-jquery/) - for which you can see a working demonstration.

Comment: Really, you should be `wp_enqueue_script`ing those scripts with a dependency on jQuery.  +1 for the script, -1 for not using `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: @EAMann Yes you should! There are advantages in doing so. However the above method is acceptable and compliant, though if the user wishes to do so please read up on [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for which you can then place the above custom snippet into its own Javascript file `custom-char.js` and place it in the same folder as your `charCount.js` file. **(when enquing files you will be working with your `functions.php` file instead of your `header.php` file)**. +1 for suggesting `wp_enqueue_sript`, -1 for no answer/link/explanation. :D

Comment: No link/explanation because I know you know `wp_enqueue_script` :-) And I didn't leave a separate answer *because* your answer will work ... assuming jQuery is already loading. That's not the case with all themes.

Comment: @userabuser The code&scripts works when I follow the explanation and the sample in your link.
But that creates a "new" comment_field. (putting scripts & code in the head and using the html form code out the sample
in a posting which wasn't meant to do I assume)  Maybe I didn't explain well enough, I am not looking for a "new" comment_field but want to use above code or simular on the existing comment_field.  Assuming not to mess around with the core comment-template.php I am not able to do as wished. Would appreciate to be enlighten a little more if possible.

Comment: @Charles Hi, I did **not** say to copy the form fields or html from the download file at the provided link. Only the `charCount.js` file and the snippet example provided here is what you need. You need to modify the example here `disableControl: '#btnSubmit',` to match your CSS selector for the comment submit button on your existing theme. The HTML content provided in that download is demonstration only from the author.

Comment: @userabuser Thank you for clearing me up and pointing me to the right direction.I could make several excuses about the why and how but reading is what I didn't do well.
I only had to change `$("#txtTweet")` into `$("#comment")` and `#btnSubmit` into `#submit`. All is working great now, thank you for your time and effort sir!
Note: I had to load also the jquery.js to get it work, assuming that is correct.